# ACF Repeater deletes previous entries on update

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

We are having a weird problem. We have a repeater. It used to work perfectly. But now, whenever we add a new item, one of these things happen:
- recording new item with some of the fields
- not record the added item
- deleting previous entries

We tried these:
- updating wp
- updating ACF
- deleting the ACF plugin and installing a fresh one

But the bug still remains.

Please help!

Comment: have you changed the name of the repeater fields?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the field name is used elsewhere in the website, such as in another custom field page. Have a look around and see if it is duplicated anywhere.